# Can't upload MySQL database in phpMyAdmin - Migrating wordpress from local host to live site

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am at a very beginner level. I am creating a website, and did all of it with Wordpress on localhost. Now I bougth a domain name with GoDaddy hosting, and would like to pass my site from this local server to the live site.
I followed steps of these tutorials : 
http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-local-to-live/
 -//- wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

But when getting to step 4 ( for the both of them) which is "Upload Database File into New Database / Importing WordPress Database on Live Site"
I am confronted to a problem I cannot seem to resolve even with all the online manuals and forums.

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `a'
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `a`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1
  COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL error message:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'x'@'localhost' to database 'a'

-> I created a MySQL database (online) in Cpanel Interface named "arctic" user "artic" used as well "paul" or others to try to see if the problem came from that. 
--> then I exported my database on phpMyAdmin (on local) to a .sql file. changed the lines mentioning http://localhost/arctic to www.arctic-international.com  as advised in a those tutorial (the 1st one)
---> NOW I try to import this file to the phpMyAdin (online) and I get this message

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `arctic`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `arctic`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1
  COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL error message:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_arkjRXZnzq'@'localhost' to database 'arctic'

I do not understand and even tried to create user "cpses_arkjRXZnzq" and grant it all permisions but it still doesn't work.

I am not expert at all but I'm trying to learn, but I do need this site up and running and would really do with some help. SO please if you have any idea it would be great to hear about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Correction, user was "arctic" not "artic", don't know if that changes something, but just so you know :)

Comment: There's a plugin called "Duplicator". Sane people who migrate WordPress installations a lot use it. It's free. Just sayin'

Comment: Make sure the database you created in step 4 with phpmyadmin has the same name as the database on your local machine...